# Player Controller constantly rotates player when there is no input?

Tags: unity-game-engine, controller

Player controller constantly rotates the player when there is no input. The player is idle, not rotating, until the up arrow is pressed. Then it begins rotating constantly.

This happens whether mouseRotate is true or not.

If tried a number of things, including commenting out the mouserotate line altogether, as well as taking out the animations temporarily.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 //using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
 using UnityEngine.Networking;

 public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
 {
// Updated 2019-11-06 //
public float movementSpeed=1;
public float runSpeed=2;
bool isOnGround;
Rigidbody rb;
private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
private Animator anim;
public bool mouseRotate = true;
public float rotationSpeed = 200f;

void Start()
{

    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update()
{
    updateAnim();
    ProcessJumping();

    moveDirection.y -= 10f * Time.deltaTime;

    if (mouseRotate)
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")) * Mathf.Sign(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")), Space.World);//mouse rotate

        if (Input.GetKey("up") || Input.GetKey("down"))
        {
            transform.Translate(0, 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("left") || Input.GetKey("right"))
        {
            transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * runSpeed, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    else//traditional keyboard controls-- can implement menu to choose rotation style
    {
        // updated by Yizhi 11/10/2019
        if (Input.GetKey("up") || Input.GetKey("down"))
        {
            transform.Translate(0, 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("right") || Input.GetKey("left"))
        {
             transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed, 0);
        }
    }




}

void ProcessJumping()
{
    CheckIfOnGround();
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isOnGround)//(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isOnGround)//removed until network control implememnted
    {
        transform.Translate(0, 0.75f, 0);
        isOnGround = false;
        anim.SetBool("Jump_b", true);
    }


}


void CheckIfOnGround()    {
    Ray[] rays = new Ray[3];
    rays[0] = new Ray(transform.position - Vector3.right * .45f, Vector3.down);
    rays[1] = new Ray(transform.position, Vector3.down);
    rays[2] = new Ray(transform.position + Vector3.right * .45f, Vector3.down);

    RaycastHit hit;
    float maxD = .1f;

    foreach (Ray ray in rays)
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxD))
        {
            if (hit.collider != null)
            {
                isOnGround = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isOnGround = false;
            }
        }
    }
}


void updateAnim()
{
    if ( (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift)))//(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) ||//temporarily removed until network controls are added. Left keyboard belongs to julie, right keyboard belongs to dot
    {
        // Updated 2019-11-06 //
        anim.SetFloat("Speed_f", runSpeed);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        // Updated 2019-11-06 //
        anim.SetFloat("Speed_f", movementSpeed);
    }
    else
    {
        //ELSE idle
        anim.SetFloat("Speed_f", 0);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a reason for using all these `if(Input.GetKey(XY))` at all? Anyway you are then using `GetAxis(XY)` for the movement/rotation .. you could basically do it in one go in one line for moving and one line for rotating .. I'm quite confused by your code and trying to figure out what it is supposed to do ... You should probably also remove all comments that are not relevant for this question since they bring a lot of clutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You setup your rigidbody to not rotate your object by locking those rotational axis on the rigidbody component, then if you do need to rotate your player you can manually do it through code. This has been the approach I have successfully used in the past. :)